# problems with : php7.0-fpm

Tags: php

SO: ‪Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS‬ + Plesk Obsidian - 18

I have a VPS, and every time it tries to install or update something, I get errors. In the end, it seems that everything points to the installation of `php7.0-fpm`.

What can I do?

```
Unsafe symlinks encountered in /run/php, refusing.
Job for php7.0-fpm.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status php7.0-fpm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details                                                                                        .
invoke-rc.d: initscript php7.0-fpm, action "start" failed.
● php7.0-fpm.service - The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.0-fpm.service; enabled; vendor prese                                                                                        t: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/php7.0-fpm.service.d
           └─limit_nofile.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since jue 2020-06-18 10:52:00 CEST; 34ms a                                                                                        go
  Process: 3296 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.0 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/p                                                                                        hp/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=78)
  Process: 3283 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/php/php7.0-fpm-checkconf (code=exited, sta                                                                                        tus=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3296 (code=exited, status=78)

jun 18 10:52:00 h2722569.stratoserver.net php-fpm7.0[3296]: [18-Jun-2020 10:5...
jun 18 10:52:00 h2722569.stratoserver.net php-fpm7.0[3296]: [18-Jun-2020 10:5...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete php7.0-fpm (--configure): el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
Se encontraron errores al procesar: php7.0-fpm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the pool definiton of php-fpm (www.conf) which is in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d`. I think that you are trying to start the php-fpm process as user "vagrant" - a user that doesn't seem to exist in the box.

The user and the group www-data is used to run php-fpm:

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
```